# How do inherited classes access data stored in a base class container?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to access data from a base class container from multiple inherited classes. I've previously looked into other stackoverflow questions on either static vectors and shared_ptr or unique_ptr however I'm not sure these are the best way forward (and I'm unfamiliar with how to implement shared_ptr or unique_ptr). Please see code below.

```
class Event {
public:
  Event(){}
  virtual ~Event(){}
  std::vector<int>& testData() {return test;} // return reference.
private:
  std::vector<int>test; 
};

class InheritedEvent1 : public Event
{
public:
  void FirstMethod(void);
};

class InheritedEvent2 : public Event
{
public:
  void SecondMethod (void);
};

void InheritedEvent1::FirstMethod(void){
testData().push_back(1); // Insert data into Event vector.
std::cout << "FirstMethod: size " << testData().size() << std::endl;
}

void InheritedEvent2::SecondMethod(void){
std::cout << "SecondMethod: size " << testData().size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
InheritedEvent1 First;
InheritedEvent2 Second;
First.FirstMethod();
Second.SecondMethod();
}
```

In this example specifically, both of the methods attempt to access the same vector yet they appear to be creating / accessing their own copy of the container. Any and all suggestions greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what's the problem exactly?

Comment: You could jusr as well make your data public. Returning a reference to private data is a silly way to circumvent the letter of the guidelines that insist on making your data private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want all of the inherited classes to share the same vector.  In which case, a static vector in the base class would make sense.

As you did not describe the exact problems encounterd, I can only imagine that you were not initializing this static data member properly.

Here is implementation above which prints 1 for each call.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Event {
public:
  Event(){}
  virtual ~Event(){}
  std::vector<int>& testData() {return test;} // return reference.
private:
  static std::vector<int> test; 
};
std::vector<int> Event::test; 

class InheritedEvent1 : public Event
{
public:
  void FirstMethod(void);
};

class InheritedEvent2 : public Event
{
public:
  void SecondMethod (void);
};

void InheritedEvent1::FirstMethod(void){
testData().push_back(1); // Insert data into Event vector.
std::cout << "FirstMethod: size " << testData().size() << std::endl;
}

void InheritedEvent2::SecondMethod(void){
std::cout << "SecondMethod: size " << testData().size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
InheritedEvent1 First;
InheritedEvent2 Second;
First.FirstMethod();
Second.SecondMethod();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- If you know the operations that you want the inherited classes to perform over the container, better make the protected member functions that do just that, for e.g. `addItem` instead of returning reference. Also, give a public API e.g. `const ItemType& itemAt(int index) const;`. This way you can change the implementation at any time, such as some other container instead of vector or some fast caching over the container etc.
- If you only want the derived classes to update the container using the reference, which is very likely, make the `testData` a protected member instead of public.
- If you want to give your inherited classes all the freedom, you may make the vector member variable protected. But, still try to give a more helpful and constrained public API.
- It is very unlikely that you return the container reference in a public member. If it is the case then your current code looks fine. I don't see shared_ptr or unique_ptr adding any advantage. shared_ptr might be useful if you want two or more objects to have ownership of the container but I still can't see why you will do it for the specific case you have posted.

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. I've made some changes to my code based on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can write code like this, but you should NOT do it.

I think you need not write code like this at most time(99.9999%).

The code is just unreasonable.

Derived class do not need get any reference of private members in base class.